# Custom link for each user in PHP

Tags: php

The standard GET query as a link for each user is easy but ugly for the users and search engines.

```
// This looks UGLY
website.com/index.php?userid=43232

//This is what I want
website.com/coolUser
```

How to make a custom link for every user without creating folders all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way to make URL like that, using .htaccess (create .htaccess file and upload to your public_html / wwwdir)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ index.php?userid=$1 [L]
```

Now, you can access http://yoursite.com/43232 **OR** http://yoursite.com/index.php?userid=43232

Comment: Do I have to install 'mod-rewrite' or set it up somehow? I did exactly as you said, I also did couple examples from the net, and nothing works. When I go to http://yoursite.com/index.php?userid=43232, it works, but when I go to http://yoursite.com/43232, it says 'Object not found!'.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I misspelled the file name. Thanks a lot!

Comment: maybe this can help: http://www.tutorio.com/tutorial/enable-mod-rewrite-on-apache.

Answer (score 3):

It's called "routing". Read [this article](http://www.phpaddiction.com/tags/axial/url-routing-with-php-part-one/) for more.

Answer (score 1):

What you mentioned called "clean URL", and what you need something known as "mod-rewrite" capability in Apache configuration.

Sergei and Zulkhaery direct you to it with their comments. Also you can take a look at the link below:
http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls

But don't forget you may see some problems with you css, js, and image files. But they have their own solutions too. You can find them if you get these problems.